# CSS: Broken menu layout on Linux

Tags: css, layout

I came out to curious situation with menu on http://jdem.cz/vzcy9 . I was developing it under Windows 7, FF 13/14, IE 9, Opera 11 and it displays fine there. But on any Linux browser the menu there is spread to two lines (see the image below).

I've tried to set smaller margin and padding of every menu link but it didn't help.

Do someone have some idea about where could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Add your body to <html><center><body>Your HMTL code</body></center></html>

Comment: Different fonts are available in Linux so the width of the text is going to be different most likely.  Also what browser & version is it in Linux (firefox of some kind? )

Comment: @LucasHolt yep, that looks like the font can be problem. The font is Georgia. This screenshot is from FF-10-ubuntu, but the problem was also with ff-14.1-debian, Opera-12.5-debian and so on.. You can view the BrowserShots result here: http://jdem.cz/vzdq9 
So it looks like I should use some font stack to be more compatible with Linux?

Comment: Some Linux distros have font packages that include fonts from Windows or equivalents, but you can't assume that users have them.  It's rather hard to select fonts for Linux as every distro may pick different fonts.  The liberation fonts are popular.  Most distros have something equivalent to Helvetica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your advices. It really was a problem with font (Georgia) which is not present on Linux. It's Linux equivalent was much more "wider" which broke the layout.

I added:

```
    font-family: "Lucida Serif", Lucida, "DejaVu Serif", "Bitstream Vera Serif", "Liberation Serif", Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
```

Which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of different font-rendering. Even if the font you use is the same, it may be rendered slightly differently. For this reason you should always allow for text to grow or shrink a bit without breaking your layout. In your case it can be worked around in several ways without affecting the layout much:

- By setting `white-space: nowrap` on the `#access` element.
- Set the width or max-width of the `#access a` elements.
- Reduce the horizontal margin on the `#access a` elements by a pixel or two.